# Incorrect text wrapping of site links when viewed on iPad with Firefox/Safari

Tags: bug, design, firefox, safari, ipad

When viewing the Stack Overflow Profile or Activity pages on an iPad using Firefox or Safari, some of the link texts are incorrectly wrapped to the next line. Also, some of the border lines are missing (like the text has a white fill that overlaps on the line).

Screenshots:

(*Firefox, no sidebar*)
[image: firefox no-sidebar]

(*Firefox, with sidebar*)
[image: firexfox with-sidebar]

(*Safari, with sidebar*)
[image]

Notes:

- When I scroll the page:

  - The text wrapping somehow auto-fixes itself
  - But the missing border lines are still missing
- On Safari, there's no issue with the text when there's no sidebar
- Screenshots are from meta but it's the same on the main site
- As far as I could tell, this got broken only after updating to iOS 13.3

Env:

- iPad 9.7in iOS 13.3
- Firefox for iOS 21.0
- Safari 13.0.4

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: I'm not sure, but my understanding is that this falls under the Standard (or Desktop) view/version of the website, which should be supported... In any case, I've been viewing it on the iPad for quite a long time now and this is the 1st time I've seen it displayed like this.

Comment: Looks like iPad related for sure: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337437/rendering-glitch-on-ipad and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337447/tab-design-is-broken-on-profile-page-on-ipados

Comment: @HansPassant It’s Firefox for iOS, it has its [own versioning and releases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUrEL.jpg) different from the desktop app. I guess you’re right that it’s not part of the officially supported browsers, I think I misunderstood the meaning of Standard and Mobile.